# How do I delete this file

Tags: files

I installed avast to try to get to the source of ongoing problems and found this

```
15:14:25: An error occured in avast! engine: The file is a decompression bomb
15:14:25: Couldn't delete file '/home/simon/Desktop/Ubuntu /lubuntu-12.04-desktop-powerpc.iso/casper/filesystem.squashfs'.
```

Comment: Avast is no longer supported for Linux so you shouldn't expect it to work...

Answer (score 2):

That file is part of the Lubuntu image `/home/simon/Desktop/Ubuntu/lubuntu-12.04-desktop-powerpc.iso`, which Avast apparently treats as an archive and thus searches for viruses.

The `filesystem.squashfs` in that image is **not** harmful, cannot and will not cause damage to your system, deleting it will **not** fix whatever problems you are having.

Should you still want to get rid of it, delete the Lubuntu image.

**Update**: [squashfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SquashFS) is a compressed file system, which might share some similarities with a *decompression bomb*, but the file is there for a reason. Without it, the Lubuntu image would not work. Again, it will **not** damage your PC or system in any way.

Comment: so it's not a bomb?